# WindowManager$BadTokenException near dialog.show in AsyncTask android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

How to show a dialog box in AsyncTask. Getting BadToketException in dialog.show();
I tried many ways but I could not solve it.

Also tried to pass context to the dialog box in different ways, but it is giving me the same result.

```
public class RetriveStock extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        message = client.clientReceive(1); // I get data here.

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        if (message.contains("AlertExecuted:")) {
                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(CreateAlert.this);
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.display_dialog);// Dialog layout
                TextView dialogText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.digMsg);

                dialogText.setText("Alert Executed!");
                Button ok = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok);

                ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    dialog.show(); //WindowManager$BadTokenException
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        //          progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "loading news content");
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context , AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        progressDialog.setMessage(""+getString(R.string.laodnews));
        progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.animate));
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
```

}

start dailoge in pre execute and stop in onpostexecute..

Answer (score 0):

is CreateAlert  registered activity in manifest..if not then you have to pass registered activity context

Comment: yes, it is registered activity in manifest. you mean registered activity is this right. <activity android:name=".CreateAlert"/>

Comment: if your RetriveStock is in same CreateAlert class then there is no problem to your code if it is outside of your class then you need to pass CreateAlert activity pass please check

Comment: RetriveStock is inside the CreateAlert class only.